# remove items from cache which do not have a priority of NotRemovable

Tags: c#, caching

I want to remove all items from cache except those set with a priority of CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable when added. How can I do this? Working with asp.net and c#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why don't you store the date you don't want to be removed into the HttpApplication ?

if you need to find a place where store few data that you need all around the application even in different user session I think the HttpApplicationState is the best place to do that.

Bear in mind that the HttpApplication use the cache behind the scene :-)

You could have problems if you need deploy the web application to a server farm as the
HttpApplicationState is not shared between the servers:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplicationstate.aspx

But you would have the same problem using the cache :-)